# Realm notifications registration while in write transaction

Tags: swift, realm

I understand that [you can not register](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#notifications) a `Realm` `.observe` block on an object or collection if the `Realm` is in a write transaction.

This is easier to manage if everything is happening on the main thread however I run into this exception often because I prefer to hand my JSON parsing off to a background thread. This works great because I don't have to bog down the main thread and with `Realm`'s beautiful notification system I can get notified of all modifications if I have already registered to listen for those changes.

Right now, if I am about to add an observation block I check to make sure my `Realm` is not in a write transaction like this:

```
    guard let realm = try? Realm(), !realm.isInWriteTransaction else {
        return
    }

    self.myToken = myRealmObject.observe({ [weak self] (change) in
        //Do what ever
    }
```

This successfully guards against this exception. However I never get a chance to re - register this token unless I get a little creative.

Does the `Realm` team have any code examples/ suggestions on a better pattern to avoid this exception? Any tricks I'm missing to successfully register the token?

Comment: Realm's transactions are independent on each thread. Even if you use a transaction that writes JSON in the background thread, it does not matter to the main thread. Such checking is unnecessary unless you use long transactions in the main thread.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. The solution I ended up with was creating an observe function

func() {
    guard let realm = try? Realm(), !realm.isInWriteTransaction else {
        func() // loop the method.
        return
    }
    self.myToken?.invalidate()
    self.myToken = myRealmObject.observe({ [weak self] (change) in
        //Do what ever
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the standard function, I do use an extension for `Results` to avoid this in general. This issue popped up, when our data load grew bigger and bigger.

While we do now rewrite our observe functions logic, this extension is an interims solution to avoid the crashes at a first place.
Idea is simple: when currently in a write transaction, try it again.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

extension Results {
    public func safeObserve(on queue: DispatchQueue? = nil,
                            _ block: @escaping (RealmSwift.RealmCollectionChange<RealmSwift.Results<Element>>) -> Void)
    -> RealmSwift.NotificationToken {
        // If in Write transaction, call it again
        if self.realm?.isInWriteTransaction ?? false {
            DispatchQueue.global().sync {
                Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.1) // Better to have some delay than a crash, hm?
            }
            return safeObserve(on: queue, block)
        }
        // Aight, we can proceed to call Realms Observe function
        else {
            return self.observe(on: queue, block)
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like

```
realmResult.safeObserve({ [weak self] (_: RealmCollectionChange<Results<AbaPOI>>) in
    // Do anything
})
```